# OOP best practice: Optional referenced-type parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, default-values

I know in C#, by default, referenced type variables are passed by reference to a method. I have a function which sometimes I just need its return value and sometimes both return value and the changes on the input object are needed outside of the function.

Then I wrote it as the following:

```
public static List<RuleSet> Load(XmlDocument dom= null)
{
   if (dom == null)
   {
       dom = new XmlDocument();
   }
   string path = ...
   dom.Load(path);
   List<RuleSet> ruleSets = new List<RuleSet>();
   // load the dom with file and read rules
   return ruleSets;
}
```

Sometimes I need the `dom` outside of the function and I call it `Load(dom)` and when I just need the return value I call it as `Load()`.

However, I know if the parameter was declared with `ref` I couldn't set a default value for it and there must be a reason for if, but now I did it with no problem.

Then I suspect my approach to the problem (my function above) is correct or not, or could it be implemented in a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I know in C#, by default, objects are passed by reference

That's not correct. In C#, parameters are passed by value by default. But if that parameter is a reference type (like a class or interface), then it's the reference that's passed by value, not the object itself. If you actually want to pass by reference, you need to use `ref`, `out` or `in`.

> However I know if the parameter was declared with `ref` I couldn't set a default value for it and there must be a reason for that

Yes, if a parameter is `ref`, then it basically means that it's an alias to a variable (local variable, field or array element). And a default value like `null` is not a variable.

---

What you're looking for could be solved by using two overloads instead of default value:

```
public static List<RuleSet> Load(out XmlDocument dom)
{
    dom = new XmlDocument();
    // rest of the method here
}

public static List<RuleSet> Load()
{
    XmlDocument ignored;
    return Load(out ignored);
}
```

Using `ref XmlDocument dom` and checking for `null` would also work, but I think it's less clear. The only advantage I can see with that is that it allows you to reuse the `XmlDocument`. But that's almost certainly a premature optimization.

Comment: Thank you, from object I meant instances of classes (referenced type variables). however yet a bit I suspect about the business logic of my function!